# Splash Screen MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, splash-screen

i am wondering how to achieve a custom splash screen (with progressbar) using MVVM Light.
The entry point of my application looks like

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize(); 
    }

}
```

Is there a nice tutorial how to achieve a custom splash screen?

Answer (score -1):

hi you can try this [how to add splash screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx)

**Updated** here is another one [splash screen shows load progress](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF)

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: i already found this one. it just lets you show a image on startup but i want more. i want to give the user feedback through e.g. a progressbar

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, as the link might go dead or change. Always include the essence of the linked page so that the answer is self-contained. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)